# Loop through string with attributes and convert to array

Tags: php, arrays

I am looping through arrays that contain a string with attributes.

So I have tried this to use this code.

```
public static function parse_attributes($attributes) {
        $xml = <<<HTML
        <div $attributes></div>
HTML;

        $element_array = simplexml_load_string($xml);
        $attrs = json_decode(json_encode($element_array->attributes()), true)['@attributes'];   
        return $attrs;
    }
```

But when I loop this twice, I get out nothing from the whole loop.

Comment: Can you `print_r($attrs);`?

Comment: @aldrin27 No, I cant everything is blank.

Comment: @JitendraPurohit The loop is looping though modules, so you can say I have Sections->Rows->Modules so when I add 2 modules it just give me nothing. And if I use regex instead of SimpleXML it works, so there is something wrong with me using SimpleXML

Comment: @Fredrik Insert print_r before return then add `die;` after pribt_r

Comment: @Fredrik what regex you used ?

Comment: @aldrin27 Yes that did work, but it only print_r the section attributes now. But the array is 100% correct. Now why does this not work when this twice?

Comment: @JitendraPurohit I used `/(\w+)=("[^<>"]*"|'[^<>']*'|\w+)/` but i figured out that regex can't be perfect.